# android app freezes from code running in worker thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, freeze

I want to start a periodic event when user's location change. So i have a location listener that starts a thread and this thread post a runnable to a handler

```
public class GpsListener implements LocationListener {
private String TAG = "GpsListener";
private RefreshThread runnable = null;
private Thread thread = null;
private Context context = null;

public GpsListener(Context context) {
    // this.mapHandler = mapHandler;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
    Log.i(TAG, "latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + "\n" + "longitude: "
            + location.getLongitude());

    TestThread t1 = new TestThread(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude(), context);
    Thread t = new Thread(t1);
    t.start();

    }
}


public class TestThread implements Runnable {
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private RefreshThread thread = null;// new RefreshThread();
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private Context context;
private String TAG = "TestThread";

public TestThread(double latitude, double longitude, Context context) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "run");
    thread = new RefreshThread(latitude, longitude, context, handler);
    handler.removeCallbacks(thread);
    handler.post(thread);
    }
```

}

when the thread start i want it to keep posting the same runnable until testthread is called again (I'm not actually stopping testthread in location listener but this is not my problem right now)

```
public class RefreshThread implements Runnable {

private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private Handler handler = null;
private String TAG = "RefreshTread";
private int time = 10000;
private Context context = null;

public RefreshThread(double latitude, double longitude, Context context,
        Handler handler) {// ,
    // MapHandler
    // mapHandler) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    // this.mapHandler = mapHandler;
    this.handler = handler;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Log.i(TAG, "run");
    // while (true) {
    Log.i(TAG, "doing work");
    GetMapDataTask task = new GetMapDataTask();
    task.execute("asfasf#123", longitude + "#" + latitude);
    try {
        String response = task.get();
        Log.i(TAG, response);
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putDouble("longitude", longitude);
        data.putDouble("latitude", latitude);
        Intent intent = new Intent("updateMap");
        ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        if (response != null && !response.equals("No POI")) {
            ArrayList<String> temppoints = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (response.contains("$")) {
                String[] tempar = response.split("\\$", 2);
                temppoints.add(tempar[0]);
                response = tempar[1];
            }
            temppoints.add(response);

            for (String temp : temppoints) {
                String[] tempar = temp.split("#");
                Point temppoint = new Point(Double.parseDouble(tempar[1]),
                        Double.parseDouble(tempar[0]), tempar[2], tempar[3]);
                points.add(temppoint);
            }
            // msg.obj = points;
        } else
            points = null;
        intent.putExtra("data", data);
        intent.putExtra("points", points);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
        // msg.obj = null;
        // mapHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        // Log.i(TAG, "finished work, going to sleep");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "interrupted");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    handler.postDelayed(this, time);

}
```

}

and RefreshThrad start an asynctask that tries to connect to a web service

```
public class GetMapDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Object, String> {

private final String METHOD_NAME = "getMapData";
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://server/";
private final String WSDL_URL = "http://192.168.2.2:9999/POI/POIService?";
private String TAG = "GetMapDataTask";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "\"http://server/getMapData\"";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
    Log.i(TAG, params[0] + "," + params[1]);
    // String userInfo = params[0];
    SoapObject parameter = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    parameter.addProperty("user_data", params[0]);
    parameter.addProperty("position", params[1]);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(parameter);

    // 3. Create an HTTP Transport object to send the web service request
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL, 30000);
    httpTransport.debug = true; // allows capture of raw request/respose in
                                // Logcat

    // 4. Make the web service invocation
    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Error1");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Error2");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error while connectiong to the server";
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Error3");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Logging the raw request and response (for debugging purposes)
    Log.d(TAG, "HTTP REQUEST:\n" + httpTransport.requestDump);
    Log.d(TAG, "HTTP RESPONSE:\n" + httpTransport.responseDump);
    String processedResponse = null;
    // 5. Process the web service response
    if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapObject) { // SoapObject = SUCCESS
        SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        processedResponse = parseSOAPResponse(soapObject);
        // ... do whatever you want with this object now
    } else if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) { // SoapFault =FAILURE
        SoapFault soapFault = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
        processedResponse = soapFault.faultstring;
        try {
            throw new Exception(soapFault.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return processedResponse;
}
}
```

First i tried instead of test thread to use a service but my application was hanging at httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); 
if the service was not available(i simply didn't start it) for 30 seconds because of 
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL, 30000);
so i tried to use testThread so that this is not happening. but it does.

can you please explain why this code hangs my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler runs in the UI thread as it is where it got created.

Your asynctask runs in its own thread but then you call get() on it, which makes the UI thread (the thread of the Handler) to wait until the end of doInBackground()

This is a messy way of threading, why not just run the asyncTask?

Comment: Because every time the location changes i want to keep sending request to the web service every x seconds get the response and update my UI.

Comment: I create the handler i testthread runnable and then run it in a new thread. does that count as handler is created in uiThread still?